# why does doctrine record the wrong data?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Good morning

I am making a form with symfony 6. It works fine but the data is not good.

Here is the bad data recorded for uid

```
App\Entity\Utilisateur {#358 ▼
 -uid: "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@00000000000002c40000000000000000"
 -firstname: null
 -lastname: null
 -mail: null
 -groupes: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#359 ▶}
 -id: null
```

}

Normally, user data should be stored as first and last name.

Hoping to get your answers, thank you all

Here is the UserToGroupType code

```
      $builder
            ->add('uid', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Utilisateur::class,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group',
                ],
                'mapped' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->select('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.lastname', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('u.lastname', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => function (?Utilisateur $utilisateur) {
                    return $utilisateur->getFirstname() . ' ' . $utilisateur->getLastname();
                },
            ])
```

here is the form template

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
     {{ form_label(form.uid) }} 
     {{ form_widget(form.uid) }} 
     {{ form_help(form.uid) }}
     <div class="form-error">
        {{ form_errors(form.uid) }}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the entity Utilisateur

```
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $uid = null;
    
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $firstname = null;
    
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $lastname = null;
    
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $mail = null;
```

Comment: Hello
nobody can answer?
please, i need your help..
Thanks you a lot